# android TestToSpeech engine speak() method throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android

I write an app that will speak the word i typed in an EditText when i click the button.But when i click the button, the app crushes because of NoSuchMethodError at speck() method of TTS.The code runs without error on Virtual Device with android version 5.1 but crushes on Virtual Device with android version 4.4.2 and Xperia Z 4.4.4. Help me plz.
Here is my activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                isTTSready = true;
                int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                        | result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Language is missing",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isTTSready) {
                    String readIt = text.getText().toString();
                    tts.speak(readIt, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                }

            }
        });
}
```

And Here is the error log

```
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312): Process:     com.example.tts_test, PID: 2312
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.speak
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312):     at com.example.tts_test.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:51)
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-31 12:50:26.970: E/AndroidRuntime(2312):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Sorry for my bad English.
If this post makes u upset, i'm sorry as this is my very first question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code crash because you use

```
public int speak (CharSequence text, int queueMode, Bundle params, String utteranceId)
```

that is added in API Level 21 as you can see in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#speak(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String)).

For API lower then 21 you should use

```
public int speak (String text, int queueMode, HashMap<String, String> params)
```

Change your code to something like this:

```
if (isTTSready) {
    String readIt = text.getText().toString();

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { 
        tts.speak(readIt, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
    } else {
        tts.speak(readIt, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                String utteranceId = this.hashCode() + "";
                CharSequence charS = message;
                mTts.speak(charS, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, utteranceId);
            } else {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "MessageId");
                mTts.speak(message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map);
            }
```

Also check undefined or nullable your part code where you call .speak()

Also - check what return called function -  String or CharSequence
    if returned CharSequence - before make it as .toString() check returned result to null and undefined, after it try .toString()